# zero polynomial and degree

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials

Suppose $(x^2+3x+4)p(x)=cx$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ and $c$ is a real number. Show that $p(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

My attempt:

$\deg(x^2+3x+4)p(x)=2+\deg P=1$  $\implies$ $\deg P=-1$. Hence $P$ is the zero polynomial otherwise, $\deg P\geq 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: Almost.  The degree of a polynomial can't be $-1$.  The degree of the zero polynomial is usually undefined (although some define it as $-\infty$). What is true is that the degree of the product of two **nonzero** polynomials is the sum of their degrees.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How funny that you started your comment with exactly the same first words as I did in the answer I wrote in parallel (I didn't copy)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the polynomials are in $K[x]$ for a field $K$. Then the degrees are additive so that, for $c\neq 0$ we would obtain $2+\operatorname{deg}(p)=1$, which is impossible by the definition of degree. Hence $c=0$ and $p=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Almost.
The degree of the zero polynomial is conventionally $-\infty$ (so that for all $P$, $\deg(0\cdot P)=-\infty+\deg P=-\infty$). And the degree of $cx$ need not be $=1$, we can only be sure that it is $\le 1$ (and in fact, we here must have $c=0$ and so degree $-\infty$ once again).

Admittedly, computing with case distinctions or inequalities instead of equalities for degrees may seem cumbersome if you are not used to it. So alternatively, you can form your computation into an indirect proof: *Suppose* $p$ is not the zero polynomial. Then $\deg p\ge 0$, then by your computation $\deg p\le -1$, contradiction.